# How to get Jacoco Integration test Report to work with Jenkins

Tags: ant, jenkins, code-coverage, jacoco, integration-testing

I am trying to have my integration(JavaAgent) tests automatically display test results in Jenkins. Currently I do not know of a better way to do this than to

1) Run integration tests using JavaAgent and output a Jacoco.exec.(Currently using file)

2) Write a shell script to copy .exec/.classes/.bin to the designated jenkins build.

3) Run the Jenkins Jacoco Plugin to show coverage.

However, the Jacoco Plugin wont pick up my .exec file. It only picks up my classes, so it always show 0% coverage.

I created 3 folders: exec, classes, src and copy the required files to those locations. I can see that my classes are read correctly on jenkins but the exec files is never picked up despite having the same Syntax.
I have tried **/exec, **/*.exec, **/jacoco.exec and several other ones.
**/classes and **/*java seems to be working but not for exec.

Comment: See couple of my posts related to Jenkins jacoco, you'd get what you need.

Answer (score 4):

This is what you need.

For ex: Assuming you have a Java project, in your project **ProjectABC**

- src/main/java : Here you'll have your main source code
- src/test/java : Here you'll have test source code. These are Unit tests.
- src/xxxTest/java: Here you'll have some xxx tests code (where xxx can be integrationTest, acceptanceTest, seleniumTest or some kind of non-Unit tests.

Depending upon Maven/Ant/Gradle build system, when you'll run build and test (**Note**: **Unit tests** runs for free in Maven and Gradle).

As any of these build system uses Java to run, once the build is done, you'll have one jacoco .exec file generated within Maven/Gradle/ANT's JAVA JVM for your Unit tests. I name the file generated for Unit tests as **jacocoUT.exec** (i.e. jacoco exec file for Unit tests only).

As your build/test/jar/war/etc is done, you now have everything that's required to run your project's .war/.ear file behind Tomcat/similar container.

Let's assume your project created *projectabc.war* file and you are using Tomcat.

You know that for running any **non-Unit** tests there are two things:
1. You need Tomcat/similar - this requires another JAVA/JVM (i.e. which Tomcat will use).

2. You need .war file and also jacocoagent.jar file. During Unit tests run, you would have generated a jacocoagent.jar file (or you can google around to get this file) if your Unit tests have used jacoco to generate code coverage.

**Now, these are the actions to get non-Unit tests code coverage (for ex: for Integration tests)**

I'll attach jacocoagent.jar first to my Tomcat's startup script (shell script) etc. This can be done if you add the following to some OPT variable that is already used within your Tomcat start script OR you can create a new variable called EXTRA_OPTS="..." and then use it in Tomcat startup script.
What you are actually doing here is, you can attaching jacocoagent.jar to Tomcat's JVM (considered as external JVM as your application/project's .war fiel will run in this JVM). This will make jacoco visible to Tomcat now.

For ex: Lets say you created a new variable as mentioned below and added that to your Tomcat startup.sh script (when you run Tomcat, it'll be picked).

```
export PROJ_EXTRA_JVM_OPTS="-javaagent:tomcat/jacocoagent.jar=destfile=somefolder/in/your/workspace/build_or_target_or_somecustom_folder/jacoco/IT/jacocoIT.exec,append=false"
```

**NOTE**: Here I'm putting jacocoagent.jar file at tomcat folder. You can put it anywhere and use that path for the jacocoagent.jar file for *javaagent* variable.

Now, in your Tomcat's startup.sh script, you can add this variable where Tomcat actually starts. For example, snapshot of this startup script would look like:

```
## Tomcat command
TOMCAT_CMD="$JAVA_HOME/bin/java $TOMCAT_JVM_ARGS \
$OPTIT_JVM_ARGS \
... \
... \
$PROJ_EXTRA_JVM_OPTS \
-Dthc.tomcat.extrapaths=$TOMCAT_EXTRA_PATHS \
org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap $TOMCAT_CFG_FILE_ARGS start"
```

As you see above, now the variable that I created is now getting used while Tomcat will start (when we run TOMCAT_CMD variable which has the command line).

Now, when you put .war file in tomcat/webapps folder and start Tomcat's startup.sh script, you'll see a new jacocoIT.exec file at the given path(0 bytes at this time as you haven't run any non-Unit tests yet).

At this point, you'll have Tomcat up and running and your project's .war file expanded into to folder in tomcat/webapps folder + if the project is an application, then in some machine (localhost/ip x.x.x.x: port/yourCoolApp) running. It's ready now for your non-Unit tests (aka Integartion/acceptance tests / Selenium based etc tests to run). For running any non-Unit tests, you need Tomcat/similar container up/running with your project's .war/.ear etc file.

OK. At this point, you'll now run your Integration tests. You'll notice that if you are doing (tail -f catalina.out) file then, there is some activity/hit going on in catalina.out log file as the Integration tests are in progress/running.

At this point, your jacocoIT.exec file is still (0 bytes or some bytes), hang on as this is not a valid / populated jacoco code coverage file for your IT tests yet.

Lets say your IT tests (gradle / Maven way) are complete now and you'll finalyl stop your Tomcat (lets say by running some stopTomcat.sh shell script).

At this point, you'll get a fully populated jacocoIT.exec file (as after you stopped your Tomcat instance, it'll flush all code coverage data to jacocoIT.exec file).

Depending upon whether you ran IT or AT (acceptance tests) or ST (selenium tests), you can name the jacocoXX.exec file accordingly.

So, you are done with Tomcat start + running IT tests + stopping Tomcat + getting a valid / populated jacocoIT.exec file.

**NOTE**: It's important to stop Tomcat to get a populated jacocoIT.exec file otherwise, it won't be a valid code coverage file. After Tomcat is stopped, the file size increases so that's another sign that you got something good there.

You don't have to stop tomcat if you are using dumping the code coverage data within your application code somehow or using tcp way of capturing the code coverage data. This is useful when you don't want to stop Tomcat instance (i.e. what if you want to get code coverage of IT tests in INT, QA etc environment where the application need to be up and running). Look jacoco documentation how you can get code coverage without stopping Tomcat/similar app container instance.

All you have to do now is get this jacocoIT.exec (Integration tests) file sitting next to jacocoUT.exec file (Unit tests) and then use "**/*.exec" pattern; basically using both .exec files (or multiple .exec files for various tests you ran) to get the code coverage.

This is what I have done in Jenkins.

1. Main project job, checks out the code, runs build (tests included) and in main job's workspace, I have jacocoUT.exec file (if Unit tests exists and they run).
2. I trigger / call another child/downstream job to run IT tests and do the following (during this child job run, the main job is BLOCKED / sits until child finishes its work):
   a. checkout using the same change/revision set what main build job used to checkout and then export that *PROJECT_EXTRA_JVM_OPTS* variable. In Tomcat startup script, it's already used. Here I pass that my tests type is IT i.e. it'll create jacocoIT.exec file.
   b. I use Copy Artifact plugin and get the .war and jacocoagent jar file from main build job's LATEST workspace and put the files under respective locations.
   c. I start Tomcat
   d. I run integration tests.
   e. I stop Tomcat
   f. I run / publish jacoco report (jacocoTestReport in Gradle) or Jacoco plugin in Jenkins. THIS is ONLY, jacoco report for IT tests (using only jacocoIT.exec file).
3. Now the control comes back to the main project/build job and here I use
   a. Copy artifact plugin again. This time to get the jacocoIT.exec file from the CHILD job's workspace and put it under some folder/location where jacocoIT.exec file sits next to jacocoUT.exec (i.e. build/jacoco/UT/jacocoUT.exec and build/jacoco/IT/jacocoIT.exec).
4. Now, I can easily use Jacoco (Gradle's jacocoTestReport task) OR Jacoco Plugin (**/*.exec pattern) to show/get/publish COMBINED Jacoco code coverage (for both Unit and Integration tests). If have more than these 2 types of tests like for ex, jacocoST.exec (for selenium tests), you can get the same and then you'll get combined code coverage using 3 tests.

**NOTE**: Code coverage is getting to know how much code (various counters) you are covering in the MAIN source code, while running your tests (unit/integration/etc).

5. Finally, I call sonarRunner (Gradle task) or sonar analysis and set Sonar properties to read .exec files, other property values and get combined reports in Sonar as well. You should look into "Views portfolio plugin" in SonarQube (and see what it does). Using portfolio plugin, you can create various top level views and measures in Sonar across various teams, people, type of projects etc and get combined Sonar metrics.